# How do I include a graphic with a caption after some text in the same page?

Tags: graphics

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section{Power Converter Topology and Electric Machine Selection}
\subsection{Power Circuit Topology}
The choice of power circuit topology in the design of an Integrated Starter Generator system is crucial. The associated power electronics technology used in power conversion within the ISG system has important considerations in its working capabilities in numerous applications.\\ \\
Here, either of the traditional Voltage Source Inverter or the Current Source Inverter can be used for the power conversion. A conventional VSI acts as a DC-AC buck inverter or an AC-DC boost rectifier which works with the constraint that the AC output voltage does not exceed the DC bus voltage while a conventional CSI acts as a DC-AC boost inverter or an AC-DC buck rectifier which works with the constraint that the AC output voltage is higher than the input DC voltage that is fed to the inductor. The diagrams for both the inverters are shown here [Figure 2.1 and 2.2]. Due to these constraints both topologies do not prove to be efficient method for optimal ISG design and functionality for the required situation. 
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{2-1.png}
\caption{Conventional VSI Topology}
\end{figure}
\\
The high-speed procedure of induction machines in expressed in [21] with the help of a dual voltage inverter control method. The primary motive of the control strategy discusses in to achieve a stable power region of 10:1 speed range under 42V and to alleviate the issue of low voltage limit. The control strategy works well in terms of allowing the system to perform over a very large speed range with induction machines of voltage less than 42V, however the extra inverter which is analogous to the main power inverter will raise system complexity, costs and system volume. A new power converter topology for series and parallel stator winding arrangements is expressed in [22] for large speed range for the ISG system. There are multiple disadvantages associated with the discussed configuration like transition from series to parallel, high rated converter power and significant realization efforts.
\end{document}
```

This taking my figure onto a fresh page and not at the position I inserted it at in the code. What do I do to keep the figure between the paragraphs I intend it to be?

Comment: You should format your code. You have some reputation, so you should know how to do it. Then, a quick search on Google or on Tex.SE will show you plenty of solution, like not using floats, for example, or [using `\FloatBarrier` or `H`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Keeping_floats_in_their_place)

Comment: It is possible (depending on figure size)) that `\begin{figure}[ht]` will solve the problem, even leaving it as a float.

Comment: Don't use ``\\`` to end paragraphs and dont' use ``\\ \\`` to “leave a blank line. There's almost never need of a blank line, if paragraphs are well written and indented.

Comment: A floating environment is intended to float the picture (or table) to a place best fitting. If you don't want that, don't use it. You can use package `capt-of` to use caption outside a float.

Comment: it's generally a good idea to leave a blank line both before and after a float.  (in other words, input a float only at a clear paragraph break.)  it will probably not change the behavior of the float, but it may very well change the setting of the surrounding text if it's coded in the middle of a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can force floats to stay in place by adding an exclamation mark after the location placement declaration for the figure. In this case you want in exactly where it lies in the text so "here". Therefore you can write \begin{figure}[h!].

You should also remove the \\.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section{Power Converter Topology and Electric Machine Selection}
\subsection{Power Circuit Topology}
Thee choice of power circuit topology in the design of an Integrated Starter Generator system is crucial. The associated power electronics technology used in power conversion within the ISG system has important considerations in its working capabilities in numerous applications.

Here, either of the traditional Voltage Source Inverter or the Current Source Inverter can be used for the power conversion. A conventional VSI acts as a DC-AC buck inverter or an AC-DC boost rectifier which works with the constraint that the AC output voltage does not exceed the DC bus voltage while a conventional CSI acts as a DC-AC boost inverter or an AC-DC buck rectifier which works with the constraint that the AC output voltage is higher than the input DC voltage that is fed to the inductor. The diagrams for both the inverters are shown here [Figure 2.1 and 2.2]. Due to these constraints both topologies do not prove to be efficient method for optimal ISG design and functionality for the required situation. 

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{2-1.png}
\caption{Conventional VSI Topology}
\end{figure}

The high-speed procedure of induction machines in expressed in [21] with the help of a dual voltage inverter control method.
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, a `!` in the optional argument does not _force_ the positioning of a float, it just tells LaTeX to ignore certain restrictions in trying to honor the users's request.  You are perhaps hinting at the `H` specifier.